# How to sum ticked RadioButtons

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sum, radio-button

i would like to sum the ticked "Yes/No" RadioButtons from my checklist. So, it depens wheter i click on "Yes" or "No" if it should be count to sum.

This is my code so far. Unfortunately, the sum doesn't display.

```js
function checkTicked() {
  var form = document.getElementById("selected");
  let sum = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < form.length; j++) {
    if (form[j].checked == true) {
      sum = sum + 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("summe").value = sum;
}
```

```html
<form name="liste"></form>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trifft A zu?</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice0" id="selected" onchange="checkTicked()">
    Ja
  </label>
          <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice0" onchange="checkTicked()">
    Nein
  </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trifft B zu?</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" id="selected" onchange="checkTicked()">
    Ja
  </label>
          <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" onchange="checkTicked()">
    Nein
  </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" ; style="text-align:right;"><b>Summe</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="summe1" id="summe" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some issues

- closed the form too early
- missed a `<table>`
- not unique IDs
- you had an `int` instead of `let` or `var` in the for loop

To fix YOUR code you can do

```
function checkTicked() {
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]:checked");
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].closest("label").innerText.trim() === "Ja") {
      sum += 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("summe").value = sum;
}
```

But I suggest delegation and a simpler script with more information on the radio itself:

I delegate from the form instead of adding inline event handlers

You can remove the summeNEIN from the form and the second count if you only want the JA

```js
document.getElementById("liste").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  document.getElementById("summeJA").value = this.querySelectorAll("input[value=ja]:checked").length
  document.getElementById("summeNEIN").value = this.querySelectorAll("input[value=nein]:checked").length
})
```

```html
<form id="liste">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trifft A zu?</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label> <input type="radio" name="choice0" value="ja">Ja</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="choice0" value="nein">Nein</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trifft B zu?</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label><input type="radio" name="choice1" value="ja">Ja</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="choice1" value="nein">Nein</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" ; style="text-align:right;"><b>Summe JA</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="summeJA" id="summeJA" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" ; style="text-align:right;"><b>Summe NEIN</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="summeNEIN" id="summeNEIN" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```